# Android: SetText in ListView header

Tags: java, android, listview, header, android-listview

I have a ListView with a layout as header, only I want to change the text and image programmatically. I have no idea where to place it in the code. Here is my code http://plaatscode.be/141928/ (password: Android) and here is the code i want to place:

```
MenuFoto.setImageResource(R.drawable.------);
MenuTitle.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.------));
MenuInfo.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.------));
```

note: the code on http://plaatscode.be/141928/ is a fully working code.

Where do i have to place to code above to get it working?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Online about a minute a -1 already? Why? I could learn from it.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but a guess would be the code link.  A lot of people want the relevant code right there.  It's more convenient than having to click a link and go to yet another place to see the code/issue.

Comment: I didn't give you the -1.
But many people does not like it when people just dump all their code on a page and link to it, and after that ask for help. People want the code that is relevant

Comment: Sorry but i don't get how to place a full code rather than place 4 spaces in front of every line.

Answer (score 2):

**EDITED ANSWER WITH NEW INFO FROM COMMENTS**

You updated your code so I will update my answer. You are getting your MenuFoto, MenuTitle and MenuInfo in the wrong place. Instead of:

```
MenuFoto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ProductFoto);
MenuTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ProductTitle);
MenuInfo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ProductInfo);
```

Do:

```
ImageView menuFoto = (ImageView) header.findViewById(R.id.MenuFotoID);
TextView menuTitle = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.MenuTitleID);
TextView menuInfo = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.MenuInfoID);

menuFoto.setImageResource(R.drawable.------);
menuTitle.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.------));
menuInfo.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.------));
```

After:

```
ViewGroup header = (ViewGroup)inflater.inflate(R.layout.productenlistviewheader, list, false);
```

And before of:

```
list.addHeaderView(header, null, false);
```

In `MenuFoto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ProductFoto);` you are trying to get an id in your ContentView (when you do `setContentView` you define your ContentView). However, you want to get your id from your header, so you have to do findViewById on your header (that you get using the `inflate.inflate`.

Comment: I did that, I removed a part. That I think was unnecessary

Comment: Put the full code related to your `ListView`. Including xml. Also, please tell us what did fail when you did what I answered. You said in your question that you didn't know where to put the code, now you are telling us that you did this... Please add the max information you can so people don't do unnecessary answers and we can assist you more efficiently.

Comment: Sorry, your are completely right. http://plaatscode.be/141929/ is the new one, this is the full code and it's working, if i place the code from my question it gives an error.

Comment: Please tell me your error. However, I found an error at your new code and updated my answer.

Comment: So what is the solution? Sorry i found it a little confusing.

Comment: I understand it now, but it is giving the same error as before `ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 1647 
`, `Source not found`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17138/discussion-between-tiago-almeida-and-user1448927)